# Mysql select rows based on previous quarterly month from current month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query row to view registered record based on previous quarterly month, for example:

current month / year: **Jan 2018**

the query should show all records by registered month which is: **Oct 2017**, **Jul 2017**, **Apr 2017** and so on.

I use below query but only can select rows for last 3 month.

```
SELECT name, date, amount, agreement, bank
FROM `account`
WHERE (YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
```

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do arithmetic like this:

```
select a.*
from account a
where mod(month(date), 3) = mod(month(current_date), 3);
```

You seem to understand how to handle the year component, but something like:

```
and date >= curdate() - interval 1 year
```

Comment: Hi, i don't have much idea about that, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Try This One, Manually

```
select *
from account 
Where current_date >= dateadd(year, -1, Getdate())
    And Month(current_date) In (
            Month(Getdate()), 
            (Case When Month(Getdate())+3 > 12 Then Month(Getdate())+3-12 Else Month(Getdate())+3 End), 
            (Case When Month(Getdate())+6 > 12 Then Month(Getdate())+6-12 Else Month(Getdate())+6 End), 
            (Case When Month(Getdate())+9 > 12 Then Month(Getdate())+9-12 Else Month(Getdate())+9 End)
            )
```